# Angular Convert POST request data to array

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, angular, post

I have a post request that sends some data to a NodeJS app and then that returns an array. My problem is that I can't turn the data I receive as a response from the POST request to an array.

My Angular is set up like this:

```
newWord = '';
keyword = '';

onClick() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/search',
      { keyword: this.keyword },
      {
        headers: headers
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
  }
}
```

The data inside the node app looks like this:

[image]

I want to get this data in angular as an array so I can iterate over it or do anything else with the fields. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your issue. What exactly is the problem? Why cant you use the data array?

Comment: well because when i try to access any element like i do in Node.JS `.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data.id)
      })`

Comment: like that both console.log(data[0]) and data.id give me the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Object'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the type to the http request. Otherwise angular expects any, which is not necessarily an array. That is where the error comes from.

```
 this.http.post<{ id: string, text: string }[]>('http://localhost:3000/search',
      { keyword: this.keyword },
      {
        headers: headers
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
```